# Deploy harbor on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, harbor

am following below guide to setup harbor in kubernetes cluster. 
https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/blob/master/docs/kubernetes_deployment.md

It shows how to generate deployment files for kuberentes. I could generate the yaml files for harbor registry service. However, deployment files for Clair and Notary services are missing.

How can i generate the deployment files for Clair and Notary services.

Moreover, below files are also missing

```
make/kubernetes/ui/ui.deploy.yaml
make/kubernetes/ui/ui.svc.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

The Kubernetes [Helm chart for Harbor](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor-helm) helps installers of Harbor to configure the extra services and the myriad of Harbor configurations. In the readme there are options for configuring Clair, Notary, and other add ons. The chart's default and opinionated settings can be overridden.

If by chance, you are setting up Harbor on DigitalOcean Kubernetes (DOKS) then [this provisioning script](https://github.com/javajon/kubernetes-pipeline-on-doks) shows an example of using the Harbor Helm chart.

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.